# Is every set a subset of the empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I am really a beginner to set theory and I read that the empty set is a subset of every set vacously.
however is it true that every set is a subset of the empty set for the same reason?

Comment: Is it true that $\{1\} \subseteq \varnothing$?

Comment: @ randall Vacuously yes?

Comment: That would mean that $1 \in \varnothing$. That is **not** true vacuously (or otherwise).

Comment: If you were right, every set would be a subset of every other set, by transitivity.  Like, the even numbers a subset of the odd ones, and so on.

Comment: Every set is a *superset* of the emptyset.  Perhaps this is what you were thinking about...

Comment: You should stop and look hard at what it means to be a subset.  $X\subseteq Y$ iff for every $x\in X$ you have that $x\in Y$.  For example, $\{1,2\}$ is a subset of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ since indeed for each of the elements of $\{1,2\}$, namely $1$ and $2$, you have that they are also elements of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  On the other hand, $\{1,2,3\}$ is not a subset of $\{2,5\}$ since there are some elements, namely $1$ and $3$, who are elements of the set on the left who are not elements of the set on the right.  In the same way, $\{1\}$ is not a subset of $\emptyset$ since $1\notin \emptyset$.

Comment: A rephrasing of being a subset you should find helpful... $X$ is a subset of $Y$ if and only if we can not find an example of an $x\in X$ such that $x\notin Y$.

Comment: @JMoravitzOh sorry I must not quite understand what vacuous truth means

Comment: Vacuous truth occurs when there are no elements in the universe of discourse to consider and verify the properties of.  It is vacuously true that $\emptyset$ is a subset of $Y$ regardless what $Y$ is because as we ask if for all $x\in \emptyset$ whether or not $x\in Y$ we find that there *are* no $x$ to question the property of.  Similarly, "*All presidents of the eating cheese on the moon club have been named Fred*"... implicitly this could actually read "*All presidents of the eating cheese on the moon club* (**if any even exist in the first place**)..."

Comment: Since I cannot find an example of a president of the eating cheese on the moon club whose name *isn't* Fred, (*there are none since the club doesn't even exist*) the statement is considered true.  The statement did not require that the number of past presidents of the eating cheese on the moon club be nonzero.

Comment: I think OP doesn’t understand what subset means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, normally if $A \subset B$, then $B \subset A$ is not true.
For example: The set $\{1\}$ is not a subset of $\{\}$.

Comment: It is necessary to point out the usage of the symbol $\subset$ in this post assumes that $\subset$ means *proper subset*, i.e. that it is a subset and is unequal.  Other authors use $\subsetneq$ for this.  Some authors use this symbol instead as being a subset regardless of whether it is a proper subset or not in which case it is possible that $A\subset B$ and $B\subset A$ are simultaneously true which happens precisely when $A=B$.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, lets try the following: Let $\{1\} \subseteq \varnothing$. This would mean that $1 \in \{1\}$ and $1 \in \varnothing$. However, by definition of the empty set, we have $\forall x : x \notin \varnothing$. Therefore, having $1 \in \varnothing$ would mean that $\varnothing \neq \varnothing$, which isn't the case. Therefore, $\{1\} \nsubseteq \varnothing$.

You can now generalize this to any set $A$, by using $a \in A$.

Hope that helps.